# Implementing REST-api with different defaults format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest

I have a little REST-controller named password_resets, it has only create, show and update methods.

In routes.rb:

```
resources :password_resets, :only => [:create, :show, :update]
```

and I want one of the actions can manipulate with json by default, but others not. For all actions I can do:

```
scope :defaults => {format: 'json'} do
  resources :password_resets, :only => [:create, :show, :update]  
end
```

but how to do the same only for one action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use multiple lines to setup differents formats:

```
resources :password_resets, :only => [:create, :update]
resources :password_resets, :only => [:show], :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
```